# Clipboard sharing is not working, but the screen resolution resizing is, after I setup "spice-guest-tools" on a win 11 VM

Tags: qemu, kvm

I'm running Kubuntu on the host.

I've installed a VM using QEMU/KVM and virt-manager.  The VM OS is Windows 11 Pro.  I've setup "spice-guest-tools" on the VM, and setup "spice-vdagent" on my host.

I have the channel for the spice guest tools:

```html
<channel type="spicevmc">
  <target type="virtio" name="com.redhat.spice.0" state="disconnected"/>
  <alias name="channel0"/>
  <address type="virtio-serial" controller="0" bus="0" port="2"/>
</channel>
```

The resolution of the screen is now able to adjust (which is one of the things spice-guest-tools does).

But I cannot get the clipboard to work.

Any suggestions?